# (Verification) $x \in cl(A)\setminus A \Rightarrow x \in bd(A)$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

A is a set in Metric Space (M, d) with metric d.

cl(A) denotes closure of A and bd(A) denotes boundary of A

**Claim**

$x \in cl(A)\setminus A \Rightarrow x \in bd(A)$

**Proof**

If $x \in cl(A)\setminus A$ then $x \in cl(A)\cap(M\setminus A)$.

Then since $M\setminus A \subset cl(M\setminus A)$, $x \in cl(A) \cap (M\setminus A)$.

Thus, by definition $x \in bd(A)$ which is same to $cl(A)\cap (M\setminus A)$

Comment: What have you tried? What is A? Start by writing out the definitions of the boundary and closure.

Comment: @Dman edited the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attempt, line $(1)$ and line $(2)$ conclude the same thing.

Proceed like this: let $x\in \bar{A}\setminus A$. We want to show $x\in \text{bd}{A}$. Recall $\text{bd} A = \bar{A}\cap \overline{A'}$. We already know that $x\in \bar{A}$.

To show that $x\in \overline{A'}$ we must show that $B(x,r)$ contains a point in $A'$ for every $r>0$. Now suppose that this is **not** true. Then there exists **at least one** $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)$ contains no point of $A'$ and so for this $r$, $B(x,r)\subseteq A$. But then $x\in A$...

Comment: then is the converse of the claim also true?

Comment: What do you think? HINT: what if $A$ is closed?

Comment: I think the converse if false. if x in $cl(A)\cap cl(M\setminus A)$, x is in both set closure of A and closure of M\A. but if x is in A, this would make make x is not in  $cl(A)\setminus A$. Let's think about the example set - A={x}. Then its boundary is {x} so supposition is satisfied. but $cl(A)\setminus A$ is empty so x is not in it. @Dman

Comment: You are right, the converse is false. When giving a counter example you need to specify what your metric space $(M,d)$ is, that is specify the set AND the metric. I assume in your example you are using $(\mathbb{R},d_E)$ where $d_E$ is just the standard euclidean metric $d(x,y) = |x-y|$. Then your example is fine.

Comment: thanks to stimulate my brain to work its own duty. @Dman

Answer (score 0):

bd A = cl A - int A.
int A subset A.
Thus
cl A - A subset cl A - int A = bd A.

Comment: Please use some mathjax to make this more readable.